# Test if collections.Mapping is equal to other mapping, or dict

Tags: python, python-collections

I have written a custom mapping class that inherits from `collections.Mapping`. Is there an easy way to test if an instance's data is equal to another mapping object, e.g. `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Write `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods that perform this comparison.

Comment: I was hoping there are generic implementation of such methods for mappings that can be reused.

Comment: If you derive from `dict` you get comparisons to `dict` for free, but I assumed there was some reason you didn't do that.